# Tensor and Hom are bi-adjoint functors for finite dimensional vector spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U$, $V$ and $W$ be finite dimensional vector spaces over a field $\mathbb{F}$. It is well known that $U\otimes_\mathbb{F}-$ and $\mathrm{Hom}_\mathbb{F}(U,-)$ are adjoint functors in the sense that $\mathrm{Hom}_\mathbb{F}(U\otimes_\mathbb{F}V,W)\cong\mathrm{Hom}_\mathbb{F}(V,\mathrm{Hom}_\mathbb{F}(U,W))$.

A naive observation is that they are also adjoint in the sense that $\mathrm{Hom}_\mathbb{F}(V,U\otimes_\mathbb{F}W)\cong\mathrm{Hom}_\mathbb{F}(V,\mathrm{Hom}_\mathbb{F}(U^*,W))\cong\mathrm{Hom}_\mathbb{F}(U^*\otimes_\mathbb{F}V,W)\cong\mathrm{Hom}_\mathbb{F}(\mathrm{Hom}_\mathbb{F}(U,V),W)$.

Hence, for finite dimensional vector spaces, $U\otimes_\mathbb{F}-$ and $\mathrm{Hom}_\mathbb{F}(U,-)$ are bi-adjoint, right?

Comment: Crossposted: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/207220/tensor-and-hom-are-bi-adjoint-functors-for-finite-dimensional-vector-spaces

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This holds more generally if $U$ is a finitely presented projective module over a commutative ring, with no hypotheses on $V$ or $W$.

Comment: Thank you. But It is not clear to me that the definition of finitely presented. Can you briefly give a definition?

Comment: @Hede: a module is finitely presented if it has a finite presentation: a presentation with a finite number of generators and relations.

Comment: Thanks. Hence a finitely presentated module is a finite generated module such that there are only finite relations on the generators. Right? @QiaochuYuan

Comment: @Hebe: that depends on where you think the quantifiers are in that statement.